Prisma client table names generated from introspect have mismatching case
I have a sql server database with all tables in upper snake case (e.g., APPLICATION_USER). I ran npx prisma db pull and it generated the prisma schema as expected (table names in schema.prisma are all upper snake case). However, in the prisma client, the table names look like this:
prismaClient.aPPLICATION_USER.findMany()

Column names are fine though:
prismaClient.aPPLICATION_USER.findMany({
  select: {
    APPLICATION_USER_ID: true
  }
})

How can I fix this?
